# Backpacking with incontinence

Tags: backpacking

Suggestions on how to backpack with urinary incontinence? Not a fun topic, but I’m headed out on a 5-day backpacking trip and am concerned how to pack out any used products without attracting bears.

Comment: :1 good question! You can get compostable, organic cotton based liners now - I use the pad equivalent - though not sure how you would cope in a LNT senario, they're better for the environment being plastic free, as an additional consideration :)

Answer (score 14):

You do not mention your gender, but if you are male and incontinence is urinary only:

Consider a "Male External Condom Catheter" or 'Texas Catheter', the volume of required supplies is much lower than diaper type incontinence products, it will also last much longer before needing to be addressed.  With a leg bag, you could empty it as needed, and only require a change once a day or so.

When you have used a days supply, they are easy to rinse and pack out for disposal, As they don't absorb the fluid they will be much lighter to pack as well.

If you are female, you could conceivably use an internal cath, but the I would not recommend it, there are hygiene and abrasion considerations, as well as increased risk of UTI.

Answer (score 11):

There probably isn't a big concern about bears being attracted to your stash since they would much rather have your food, but you could either:

1. Hang it just like you would your food.
2. Place it within an [OPSAK](https://loksak.myshopify.com/collections/opsak) if hanging isn't practical where you will be. You should place the OPSAK inside some kind of bag to protect against abrasion or puncture. I use the 12x20 size inside my food bag, which is the bear-proof [Ursack](https://www.ursack.com/).

Kudos to you for wanting to pack out your stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Visit your local medical durable goods store and purchase several ABD pads, which are super absorbent and can hold a considerable amount of urine and, being cotton, are biodegradable and can be burned or buried.